# Rails is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible exec ruby code that is in a instance variable in a controller?

Example:

```
def something
@code = "redirect_to 'https://www.google.com/'"
exec(@code) // And then it would redirect.
end
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? There could be a better way to solve your issue.

Comment: Definitely agreeing with Cody here. If you ever want to exec Ruby code like that, chances are that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval Yes, it is possible. I'm not sure it's a good idea though...

Comment: @cody - Just a nice way to solve my problem then. It is gonna be DRY. Travis just the answer.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This is pretty sketchy, what is the use case?!

Comment: @Dave - It is to manage, some controller code, that is dynamic.

Comment: That doesn't really help. It's just really unlikely you'd need to do this. If you don't listen to me, consider at least listening to Ryan. Describe your use case.

Comment: But you'd be executing 'redirect_to' on the server?  That doesn't make sense,  you can easily force a redirect on the browser.  There are lot's of ways to do that,  maybe I'm reading too much into your pseudo code.  If you want a controller to reach out to the Internet and do something,  you need the URI stuff in Ruby.

Comment: @RadBrad - no, it was just an example, not gonna use it for redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DON'T DO THIS. Rails IS Ruby. In Ruby, you can execute any command inside a string using the eval method. And when you start really getting into it, there is class_eval.

```
@myvar = "puts 'SHOULD NOT HAVE DONE THIS!!'"

eval(@myvar)  # SHOULD NOT HAVE DONE THIS!!
```

Keep safe.